# Maven deploy to remote server

Tags: maven, deployment, amazon-ec2, jetty

I want to deploy on Amazon EC2.

But I can't deploy.. i need some help.

I use *maven* project & *jetty* component.

Here is my code.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>MY_PROJ</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>

  <extensions>
    <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
    </extension>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-6</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
  <site>
    <id>EC2</id>
    <url>scpexe://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/www</url>
  </site>
  <repository>
    <id>EC2</id>
    <url>sftp://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/www</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

**setting.xml**

```
<server>
  <id>EC2</id>
  <username>ubuntu</username>
  <privateKey>c:\MY_KEY.pem</privateKey>
  <passphrase></passphrase>
  <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
  <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
</server>
```

And, they have an error.

situation 1. run (mvn) site-deploy

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:deploy (default-deploy)
>   on project sabo_proj_mvc: Error uploading site: Error performing
>   commands for file transfer: Exit code 1 - A 'ssh' is not an internal
>   or external command, operable program, or Batch file.

situation 2. run (mvn) deploy

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-
>   plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MY_PROJ: Failed to
>   retrieve remote metadata
>   com.XXX:MY_PROJ:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer
>   metadata com.XXX:my_proj:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to EC2
>   (sftp://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/www): Cannot
>   connect. Reason: Session.connect: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect

help me plz

ps. Refer to this [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html) => http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

Answer (score 1):

In your both situation, reason is clearly identified by maven.

> A 'ssh' is not an internal or external command, operable program, or Batch file.

Do you have ssh command? is it included in your $PATH?

> Cannot connect. Reason: Session.connect: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

This could be due to firewall restrictions, maybe remote host doesnt allow connection from your host. Verify if you are able to establish ssh connection from your host to remote